# MemSQL multi-operations transactions

Tags: singlestore

It's not clear from MemSQL documentation whether multi-operations transactions are supported or not.

In simple words let's say I have the following transaction

```
BEGIN 
INSERT smth INTO table1
INSERT smth INTO table2
UPDATE table2 SET smt
DELETE FROM table3 WHERE smth
COMMIT
```

Will this be an atomic operation meaning that either the whole transactions succeeds or rollbacks if it lease one operand fails?

Answer (score 2):

These are supported, yes. You can observe this, if you run rollback, or if you run select queries from another client prior to the commit, you will see none of the DML effects.

Comment: Is there anything that is not supported? As an example I know that INSERT...SELECTS can not be run inside transactions since, as I guess, only READ_COMMITTED isolation level is supported. Would you mind adding anything else to the list?

Comment: Where did you see that insert selects can't be run inside transactions? It should work:

Comment: ```
memsql> create table t (a int, b int);

memsql> begin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

memsql> insert into t values (1, 2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

memsql> insert into t select * from t;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

memsql> select * from t;
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |
|    1 |    2 |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

memsql> rollback;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

memsql> select * from t;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: I meant 

INSERT [IGNORE] [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
    SELECT ...
    [ ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
      col_name = insert_expr
        [, col_name = insert_expr] ... ]
https://docs.memsql.com/docs/insert

Comment: That is the query I used: insert into t select * from t. Sorry, code blocks in comments don't seem to be allowed. http://pastebin.com/FV8kY9dL

Comment: Yes, it was just a mistake in the docs. There are unsupported cases though, when insert select is across partitions.